# How to place odd elements in a grid on all rows of a specific column and even elements on a different column?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

So I'm trying to create a timeline with CSS for my online resume. My plan is to make a grid with two basic columns and a third column between them for the line and its styling. I want to place every other element on the right side of the line (the third column of the grid). Is there a way to use `:nth-child(odd)`, or something similar, to achieve this? I can of course use `grid-area`, but I'd rather not place every element individually.

This is my current grid:

```
.timeline {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49% 2px auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
      "event1 line . "
      " . line event2"
      "event3 line . "
      " . line event4"
      "event5 line . "
      " . line event6";
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  grid-area: line;
  background-color: black !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.timeline :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: event1;
}

.timeline :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: event2;
}

.timeline :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: event3;
}

.timeline :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: event4;
}

.timeline :nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: event5;
}

.timeline :nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: event6;
}
```

It works, but there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: If you have already had a go at building your grid please add the code to your post. Even if it's not exactly what you want or doesn't work as you expect, adding code will make it much easier for other contributors to advise you.

Comment: Yes of course! I have updated my question now:)

Comment: Please post your HTML. You'll get more answers (and not have your question closed for violating guidelines) when contributors can reproduce the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows.

```js
const addTask = () => {
  const D = document,
    timeline = D.querySelector('ol.timeline'),
    taskElement = D.createElement('li'),
    span = D.createElement('span'),
    div = D.createElement('div');

  span.classList.add('connection');
  div.textContent = timeline.children.length + 1;
  taskElement.append(span, div);
  timeline.appendChild(taskElement);
}

document.querySelector('#addEntry').addEventListener('click', addTask);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

:root {
  --timeline_connector_position: 30%;
  --timeline_margin: auto;
  --timeline_gapSize: 0.2rem 0rem;
  --timeline_centre: 5vw;
  --timeline_width: 90vw;
  --timeline_padding: 0.5rem;
  --timeline_taskBackground: #fff;
  --timeline_taskBackground_even: #f90;
  --timeline_taskBackground_odd: limegreen;
  --timeline_taskBorder: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_taskBorder_even: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_taskBorder_odd: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_color: brown;
}

ol,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.timeline {
  display: grid;
  width: var(--timeline_width);
  margin: var(--timeline_margin);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--timeline_centre) 1fr;
  grid-gap: var(--timeline_gapSize);
  background: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, transparent calc(50% - var(--timeline_centre)/6), var(--timeline_color) calc(50% - var(--timeline_centre)/6), var(--timeline_color) calc(50% + var(--timeline_centre)/6), transparent calc(50% + var(--timeline_centre)/6), transparent);
}

li {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--timeline_gapSize);
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-area: auto / 1 / auto / span 2;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--timeline_centre);
  grid-template-areas: "text connection";
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  grid-area: auto / 2 / auto / span 2;
  grid-template-columns: var(--timeline_centre) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "connection text";
}

li>div {
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground);
  padding: var(--timeline_padding);
  grid-area: text;
}

li:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground_odd);
  border: var(--timeline_taskBorder_odd, --timeline_taskBorder);
}

li:nth-child(even)>div {
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground_even);
  border: var(--timeline_taskBorder_even, --timeline_taskBorder);
}

span.connection {
  grid-area: connection;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent, transparent calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) - 3px), var(--timeline_color) calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) - 3px), var(--timeline_color) calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) + 3px), transparent calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) + 3px), transparent);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li:nth-child(odd)>span.connection {
  background-position: left;
}

li:nth-child(even)>span.connection {
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<button id="addEntry">Add a new entry</button>

<ol class="timeline">
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut explicabo quas esse, odio accusantium minus. Asperiores mollitia est, iusto corrupti quibusdam ipsa, assumenda nam id animi quod, nesciunt placeat. Perferendis!</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>6</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>7</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>8</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>9</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="connection"></span>
    <div>10</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z4sfxkh7/).

In the demo, above, we mark up the timeline and its entries as follows:

```
<!-- use of an ordered list for the timeline itself: -->
<ol class="timeline">
  <!-- each timeline entry is nested within and <li> element: -->
  <li>
    <!-- this could have been replaced by a pseudo-element and, perhaps
         should have been; its use is purely presentational and serves to
         connect the 'task' to the 'timeline' graphic: -->
    <span class="connection"></span>

    <!-- the <div> is used to wrap the text of the timeline entry: -->
    <div>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut explicabo quas esse, odio accusantium minus. Asperiores mollitia est, iusto corrupti quibusdam ipsa, assumenda nam id animi quod, nesciunt placeat. Perferendis!</div>
  </li>
  <!-- other entries omitted for brevity -->
</ol>
```

The reason we've nested the timeline entries is largely because CSS subgrid is, as yet, unsupported in the majority of browsers and this is a simple means by which we can offset the `<li>` entries appropriately, as the CSS – *hopefully* – illustrates:

```
/* I've used quite a lot of CSS variables for purposes of theming,
   retain or discard at your pleasure! */
:root {
  --timeline_connector_position: 30%;
  --timeline_margin: auto;
  --timeline_gapSize: 0.2rem 0rem;
  --timeline_centre: 5vw;
  --timeline_width: 90vw;
  --timeline_padding: 0.5rem;
  --timeline_taskBackground: #fff;
  --timeline_taskBackground_even: #f90;
  --timeline_taskBackground_odd: limegreen;
  --timeline_taskBorder: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_taskBorder_even: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_taskBorder_odd: 1px solid #000;
  --timeline_color: brown;
}

ol.timeline {
  display: grid;
  /* Using some of the defined CSS custom properties to set
     the width and margin: */
  width: var(--timeline_width);
  margin: var(--timeline_margin);

  /* Here we define the three-column layout, comprising of
       column 1: 1 fractional unit,
       column 2: defined by the --timeline_centre custom property,
       column 3: 1 fractional unit: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--timeline_centre) 1fr;
  grid-gap: var(--timeline_gapSize);
  /* This background defines the 'timeline' vertical stroke: */
  background: linear-gradient(
    /* the gradient moves from left to right: */
    to right,
    /* is transparent at the start of the gradient: */
    transparent,
    /* remains transparent until the point calculated by the
       CSS calc function; here we're calculating a pixel-value of
       50% width of the element, minus the width defined by the
       --timeline_centre value divided by six (the six is arbitrary
       but provided a good-enough visual in the JS Fiddle and Snippet,
       adjust to taste): */
    transparent calc(50% - var(--timeline_centre)/6),
    /* at the same point as above the colour changes to the colour
       defined by the --timeline_color custom property: */
    var(--timeline_color) calc(50% - var(--timeline_centre)/6),
    /* the change here is that we add, rather than subtract the value
       in order that the --timeline_color spans across the 50% mark: */
    var(--timeline_color) calc(50% + var(--timeline_centre)/6),
    /* at the same point that the --timeline_color ends the transparent
       value resumes; this creates hard colour stops rather than
       fading gradients: */
    transparent calc(50% + var(--timeline_centre)/6),
    transparent
  );
}

li {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--timeline_gapSize);
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  /* here the odd <li> elements are placed with the syntax of:
       row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end
     in this case the row is placed into its naturally-occuring
     row ('auto'), starts in the first column of the grid (1), ends
     in the naturally-occurring row ('auto') and spans two columns
     ('span 2'): */
  grid-area: auto / 1 / auto / span 2;

  /* we define a two-column grid, of 1 fractional unit, and one
     column equal to the size defined by the --timeline_centre
     custom property: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--timeline_centre);
  /* we name the two columns of this two-column grid: */
  grid-template-areas: "text connection";
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  /* exactly as above, but the even <li> elements start
     in the second column instead of the first: */
  grid-area: auto / 2 / auto / span 2;
  /* exactly as above but the columns are reversed in order
     that the var(--timeline_centre)/'connection' column
     overlaps the column of the same width in the parent
     grid: */
  grid-template-columns: var(--timeline_centre) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "connection text";
}

li>div {
  /* here we use some of the theming options to style the
     element: */
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground);
  padding: var(--timeline_padding);
  /* positioning the timeline entry text in the grid
     area identified by the name 'text': */
  grid-area: text;
}

li:nth-child(odd)>div {
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground_odd);
  border: var(--timeline_taskBorder_odd, --timeline_taskBorder);
}

li:nth-child(even)>div {
  background-color: var(--timeline_taskBackground_even);
  border: var(--timeline_taskBorder_even, --timeline_taskBorder);
}

span.connection {
  grid-area: connection;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent, transparent calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) - 3px), var(--timeline_color) calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) - 3px), var(--timeline_color) calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) + 3px), transparent calc(var(--timeline_connector_position) + 3px), transparent);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* here we position the connection background in order that it
   visually connects the timeline entry text to the timeline
   itself: */
li:nth-child(odd)>span.connection {
  background-position: left;
}

li:nth-child(even)>span.connection {
  background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can use `nth-child` to set the column start for the `.line` and the `.event`. However, this will create holes, so you'll also need to set `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` on the `.grid`. The line should fill two columns, so you'll need to move the background to the right position for each case.

```css
:root {
  --line-width: 5px;
  --line-height: 3px;
  --main-line-width: calc(var(--line-width) * 2 + 2px);
  --odd-line-color: gold;
  --even-line-color: silver;
}

.timeline {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr var(--main-line-width) 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  text-align: center;
}

.line {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  background: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor), 
              linear-gradient(to right, transparent var(--line-width), black var(--line-width), black calc(var(--line-width) + 2px), transparent calc(var(--line-width) + 2px));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--line-width) var(--line-height), 
                   var(--main-line-width) 100%;
  background-position: center left;
  color: var(--odd-line-color)
}

.line:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background-position: center right;
  color: var(--even-line-color);
}

.event {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  border: var(--line-height) solid var(--odd-line-color);
}

.event:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  border-color: var(--even-line-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dui elit, tincidunt sit amet dictum ut, tempus vel diam. Integer ac sem congue, ullamcorper libero sit amet, viverra dui.</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```